# Where to add the delete button? in subcomponent or overview file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a delete button into every Card to modify the state.
Should I add the button in the Card file or in the overview file(code below)? My guess would be to add it in the Card file, but then I can't access to state in the overview file anymore?

---

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import {movies} from "./movies.js"
import Card from "./Card.js"
import "./Home.css"

class Home extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            movieslist: movies   
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="homecontainer">
                {
                    this.state.movieslist.map(movie =>{
                       return <Card title={movie.title} category={movie.category} likes={movie.likes} dislikes={movie.dislikes} />
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Charlin,**

It seems that the time to start digging into Redux has come to pass. However, for the time being, and since you are using class components, meaning that I cannot offer you to use Hooks, go ahead and add that button in the Card component, but for the near future, Redux will make things easier when it comes to deal with state changes from anywhere on the app, children, parents, uncles, aunties, etc.

Please find [**here some notes about Redux**](https://redux.js.org/) and in this [other link some notes about hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). Have a good day coding!

Comment: ok so if I add the button the Card component...how do I then modify the state in the overview file? I want to make sure it gets deleted from that state

Comment: Not sure what the overview file is, you simply added the home component source code in there but we are not aware of the hierarchy for all your files, however, my best guess is that you could use the click event of the button to call a this.handleClick function and there you could update the state with a this.setState method and removing that item from the  movielist array using the splice method. That's all I can suggest for your case, bud.

Comment: home = overview file. My question is: if I add the handleClick on the Card component file, how can I then change the state in the Home file ( which is different file)?How do I connect those files?

Comment: any idea, Alvison?

Comment: In this case, once you update the state with the setState method you will have the new data on the home component state, that is the reason why you will update the state on this component.